# cannot find SQL server

Tags: python, sql, django, windows, connection

I am trying to get a python/Django app running on an alternate machine (from the one it was developed on), the dev machine is a Windows 8 64-bit machine while the new machine is a Windows 7 64-bit machine. On both machines I have DSN's that connect without any issues to the target SQL server. On the win 8 box everything works, on the Win 7 box With python and other code in the same relative places I get "**0, u'ADODB.Connection', u'Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.'**" The win 8 box has an SQL server instance installed, the win 7 box does not, they both are (theoretically) pointing at a third box, the target SQL server. Here is my settings file from the django app (the database bits) ...

```
#CHANGE THESE  TO MATCH YOUR ENVIRONMENT#
#DBHOST = 'stevecwin764\sqlx2012'
DBHOST = 'tech6\gwrwin864'
#DBHOST = 'stevecwin764\sqlx2012'
#DBHOST = 'comtech04\sqlexpress'
SITEURL = ''

ADMINS = (
# ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
   'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
    #      'NAME': 'cv_demodb',                      # Or path to database file if using   sqlite3.
       'NAME': 'cv_masterdb',                      # Or path to database file if using   sqlite3.
    'USER': 'sa',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
    'PASSWORD': 'secret',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
    'HOST': DBHOST,                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
    'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with   sqlite3.
    'OPTIONS': {
      'provider': 'SQLNCLI10',
      'extra_params': 'DataTypeCompatibility=80;MARS Connection=True;',
    },
    }
    }
```

What might cause the same code to fail on the Win7 box when it works on the Win 8 box?

Answer (score 0):

> u'Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.'"

It doesn't look like a network issue, it looks like you haven't installed the correct provider on the win7 machine. This answer has the link you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4026824/234254