# Connecting Python Script to SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, connection

I want to connect my python script to SQL server:

```
import pyodbc

conn=pyodbc.connect('Driver=SQL_Server;Server=SQLEXP;user=44;DB=test)
```

I got the following error:

> ('28000', '[28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL
>   Server]Login failed for user. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect);

and

> [28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot
>   open database "test" requested by the login. The login failed. (4060);
>   [28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Invalid connection
>   string attribute(0);

I have gone through other posts about this on blog but no solution found.

[provider cannot be found error in python connecting to SQL Server](https://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026776/provider-cannot-be-found-error-in-python-connecting-to-sql-server)

[pyodbc-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045834/pyodbc-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified)

[Connecting to Microsoft SQL server using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725862/connecting-to-microsoft-sql-server-using-python)

Comment: I attempted to add code using editing tags in post but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you use the formatting option {} to format your code as such? Don't you need a password to login to your database? The error messsage could appear if the user has no right to logon to the database.

Comment: If you pass in a user you should also pass a password

Comment: >>>Cannot open database "test" requested by the login<<< Either test db does not exists or your login is not mapped to it

Comment: Is this the actual connection string you used or am I just seeing a typo?  You're missing the closing single quote and possibly a semi-colon.  I don't really know python, but syntax would be important, also.

Comment: Actually I am using following connection code:  pyodbc.connect('Driver=SQL_Server;Server=SQLEXP;user=sa;DB=test, password=pass) @Steveo-169

Comment: I have already attempted changes suggested by you @Florian H.

Comment: Any suggetions @sepupic

Comment: any suggetions @Steve-o169

Comment: If you are sure that database test exists and online, you should just map your login to it. USE TEST; CREATE USER [44] FOR LOGIN [44]

Comment: any suggetions @Suraj Kumar.

Comment: Did you try to map your login using my code?

Comment: Looks to me like the syntax is still wrong if that's the actual connection string. Still missing a closing single quote and a couple of semi-colons. Try `pyodbc.connect('Driver=SQL_Server;Server=SQLEXP;DB=test;user=sa; pwd=pass;')`

Comment: Also, you could check out this question which has basically an identical error and seems that the asker was able to find a working string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37392476/connect-to-mssql-in-python2-7-11-windows-10-professional

Answer (score 1):

Following on from *`Steve-o169's`* comment above (below is a simple implementation):

If using **SQL Server Authentication** you can do this:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};"
                        "Server=yourServerName;"
                        "Database=yourDatebaseName;"
                        "uid=yourUserName;pwd=yourPassword")

query="SELECT TOP(10) * FROM yourTable"

df = pd.read_sql_query(query, cnxn)
```

For **Windows Authentication** I used the following:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};"
                        "Server=yourServerName;"
                        "Database=yourDatebaseName;")

query="SELECT TOP(10) * FROM yourTable"

df = pd.read_sql_query(query, cnxn)
```